# Is there a way of using PDO or Smarty to change a navigation bar if a user is logged in?

Tags: php, html, pdo, smarty

I am creating a website using Smarty and PDO, here is my header file and I'm not sure how I can make it change depending on whether a user is logged in or not?

When the user isn't logged in these options should appear (Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Sign up, Log in)
But when they sign in I want 'Sign up' and 'log in' to change to 'My account' and 'Sign Out'. Below are is the code I currently have.

```html
//If user is logged in

<div id="navigation"> <ul class="nav" id="navigation">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="hideshow" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="far fa-caret-square-down"></i></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=main">Home <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=friday">Friday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=saturday">Saturday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=sunday">Sunday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=logout" id="Logout" />Logout <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
  </li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=account">My account <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
  </li>
```

```html
//If user isn't signed in


  <div id="navigation"> <ul class="nav" id="navigation">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="hideshow" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="far fa-caret-square-down"></i></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=main">Home <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=friday">Friday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=saturday">Saturday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=sunday">Sunday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?p=signup" id="signup" />Signup <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>
  </li>


<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="index.php?p=login" id="Login"/>Login <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
</li></ul>
  {/if}
</div>
      
      
  </nav></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all assign a variable from Controller to your view, example:

`$view->assign('USER_ID', $this->auth->getUserId());`

then in template:

```
    {if $USER_ID > 0}
    {* html or template when user is logged in *}

    {* if differences are big, better is create new sub-template: *}
    {include file='./header-logged-in.tpl'}

    {else}
    {* html or template when user is not logged in *}
    {include file='./header-logged-out.tpl'}
    {/if}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks - I'm not sure what you mean by 'controller example'?

Comment: Simplify, "controller" it's a place where you create Smarty object and display templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
// User Logged In Navigation
} else {
// User Logged Out Navigation
}
```

Of course, you didn't provide enough information, this assumes your user session is set to `$_SESSION['user_id']` <-- change to whatever your session is saved as.